# Liferay 6.2: disable calendar notifications

Tags: notifications, calendar, liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2
How can I disable notifications Calendar sends when an event is created? I can change the email template but i can´t disable the notification.

Comment: I can show you a minimum viable example but I need to know a few things.  Firstly, do these changes need to be localized or is it ok for the changes to replicated in all calendar instances? In other words, do you have multiple sites where the calendar is used, and only want to have these changes affect a particular sites calendar? Secondly, have you looked at the JSP files related to the calendar yet?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes, I have multiple sites where calendar is used but i want to disable notifications for all of them. There is a notification being sended to the website admin, that is what i want to disable.
And, no, i haven't looked at the calendar JSPs, sorry i'm kind of a liferay newbie.